# jasmine testing a mock service in an angular 1.5 controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

Given the following test.
How do I ensure that the promise is resolved, and the data is *provided*.

```
describe("component: FicaStatusComponent",
    function () {
        var fs;
        beforeEach(function () {
            module("aureus",
                function ($provide) {
                    $provide.service("ficaService", function () {
                        this.status = function () {
                            return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
                                resolve([{ documentType: { id: 1 } }]);
                            });
                        }
                    })
                });

        });

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$componentController_, _ficaService_) {
            $componentController = _$componentController_;
            fs = _ficaService_;
        }));

        it("should expose a `fica` object", function () {
            console.log('should expose');
            var bindings = {};
            var ctrl = $componentController("ficaStatus", null, bindings);
            expect(ctrl.fica).toBeDefined();
        });

        it("compliant with no documents should not be compliant",
            function () {
                var ctrl = $componentController("ficaStatus");
                expect(ctrl.fica.length).toEqual(1);
            });
    }
);
```

The second test **compliant with no documents...** is failing. The length is zero. The other test is passing, so I have the correct controller being instantiated, the property is defined.

The mock service is not resolving the data correctly, probably because the `Promise` is still executing, or not being called at all.

Here is the implementation of the controller for the component:

```
var FicaStatusController = (function () {
    function FicaStatusController($log, $loc, ficaService) {
        var _this = this;
        this.$log = $log;
        this.$loc = $loc;
        this.ficaService = ficaService;
        this.fica = [];
        this.ficaService.status(1234).then(function (_) { return _this.fica = _; });
    }
```

The service is as follows:

```
var FicaStatusService = (function () {
    function FicaStatusService($log, $http) {
        this.$log = $log;
        this.$http = $http;
    }
    FicaStatusService.prototype.status = function (accountNumber) {
        var url = "api/fica/status/" + accountNumber;
        this.$log.log("status: " + url);
        return this.$http
            .get(url)
            .then(function (_) { return _.data; });
    };
    return FicaStatusService;
}());

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, u can use $q like:

```
this.status = function () {
    return $q.when([{ documentType: { id: 1 } }]);
}
```

Second, to resolve promise use $scope.$digest, $rootScope.$digest:

```
var a = $q.when({test: 1});
expect(a.test === 1).toBe(false);
$rootScope.$digest();
expect(a.test === 1).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Not $scope.$digest. It doesn't trigger a digest in root scope and won't execute promise chain.